# How to have multiple AUTH_USER_MODEL in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-auth-models

I have two different app that has separate models that inherits from AbstractionBaseUser like below

```
# in doctor/models.py
...

class Patient(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, unique=True)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['phone_number', 'email']

...
```

```
# in Patient/models.py
...

class Patient(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, unique=True)
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False, unique=True)

    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone_number'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['phone_number', 'email']

...
```

Both models have different fields

```
# in settings.py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = [
    'doctor.Doctor',
    'patient.Patient'
]
```

I tried to do this but in making migration it tells me that it must be a single model

```
AssertionError: ForeignKey(['doctor.Doctor', 'patient.Patient']) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

I read docs but I couldn't find any help

How can I fix this and how can I have multiple AUTH_USER_MODEL

Comment: You don't. You have *one* `User` model. You can make multiple extra models with a `ForeignKey` to the user model.

Answer (score 3):

> how can I have multiple `AUTH_USER_MODEL`.

**You don't**. There is *one* user model. It would also make all procedures more complicated. What if a the same email address occurs in both the `Doctor` and `Patient` model? Then how would you log in such person?

You can however make multiple extra models with a `ForeignKey` to the user model. We can for example use the default user model:

```
# settings.py

# …
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'auth.User'
# …
```

You can of course also specify a basic user model yourself. But it should be one user model.

Then both the `Doctor` and `Patient` model can have a one-to-one relation to the `User` model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Doctor(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # … extra doctor fields …
```

as well as a patient:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

class Patient(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # … extra patient fields …
```

You can then check for a user if it is a doctor by accessing the `.doctor` attribute:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def some_view(request):
    try:
        doctor = request.user.doctor
    except AttributeError:
        # … user is not a doctor …
        pass
    pass
```

This also allows that a `User` is both a `Doctor` and a `Patient` for example. This may look odd at first. But later it is possible that you introduce more roles, and it is not impossible that the same user is assigned multiple roles, for example *doctor* and *supervisor* of a department.